# How to create a client sever application and execute it

Tags: dart, dart-io

How to create client server application in dart.
My aim is to create a program to extract parameters form URL and store them in session on variable and connect the dart to .net web service and in below code i shows
The built-in library 'dart:io' is not available on Dartium.

```dart
import 'dart:core'; 
import 'dart:io';// import the dart:io library

main() {
  HttpServer server; // create the server
  server.listen("127.0.0.1", 8080); // and start listening
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I understand your question correctly, the server part of your `client server application` is a .NET web service. So you try to write the client side in Dart (the part that runs in the browser)?

You don't need to import `dart.core`.
If you want to run an app in the browser you must not import `dart:io`. `dart:io` is for Dart applications that run locally like commands you execute on the command line or launch using an icon on your desktop or that run as a background service.

In Browser applications you normally import `dart:html` instead. `dart:html` doesn't provide a lot of functionality that `dart:io` has. This is because the browser doesn't allow for example to access the local file system due to security reasons. Imagine you browse to a website and the code in this website could read, delete or upload to any server any file on your computer ...

When you have imported `dart:html` you can use the class `HttpRequest` to connect to the server.

Did you develop the .NET web service yourself?
You can easily access web services that provide a REST or JSON API. 
I don't know how to access .NET SOAP webservice with Dart though?

You can find basic instructions how to make a request to the server here https://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/

Comment: what are _ and .. in any dart program what does they do

Comment: At the beginning of a field or method to make the field or method private. In the argument list like `(_)` it is used as a variable name like 'a', 'index', ... but the convention is to use '_' as variable name to indicate that the value is ignored.
The '..' is used like 'with' in Visual Basic it is named continuation operator.
`var a = new A()..x = 50..y=30` assignes a new 'A' instance to `a` and sets `a.x = 50` and `a.y = 30`.

Comment: how to extract url paramenter and store them in session variables

Comment: I don't know what to do with your last comment.

Comment: hey how to write client part for .net server webservice can you give me any sample

Comment: It's about 5 years I worked with .NET the last time. I think you should ask a new question with a .NET tag. Why don't you want (or can't) write the server in Dart?